# EF query not returning foreign key value of navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first

I'm using EF5 Code First and Lazy Loading is disabled. I have the following code:

```
//Model
public class Task
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    //other properties that are not relevant here
    public Guid CreatorId {get; set;}
    public User Creator {get; set;}
    public Guid? OwnerId {get; set;}
    public User Owner {get; set;}
}

//Model
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //other properties that are not relevant here
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public IList<Task> TasksCreated { get; set; }
    public IList<Task> TasksOwned { get; set; }
}

//Configuration for Task
public class TaskConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Task>
{
    public TaskConfiguration()
    {           
        HasRequired(task => task.Creator)
            .WithMany(creator => creator.TasksCreated)
            .HasForeignKey(task => task.CreatorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasOptional(task => task.Owner)
            .WithMany(owner => owner.TasksOwned)
            .HasForeignKey(task => task.OwnerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

When I query against Tasks, all the data comes back as expected. When I query against Users using the following query, the Tasks property for Owner or Creator is null. The null value is assigned to whatever property does not match the User I am querying for. So, if User2 is the Owner on User1's Task, User2's ID will come back, but the Owner property will be null. This is the query:

```
var db = new MyContext();
var user = db.Users
             .Include("TasksCreated")
             .Include("TasksOwned")
             .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals("user1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

I'm not sure if there is another step I'm missing or if I don't have the proper configuration for the Task-User relationship. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i try your code and it runs.
The only difference is the constructor of the context I add:

```
public class TestEFContext : DbContext {
    public IDbSet<User> us { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Task> ts { get; set; }

    public TestEFContext(String cs)
        : base(cs) {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestEFContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestEFContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TaskConfiguration());            
    }
}
```

from here the following :

```
class Program {
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        String cs = @"Data Source=ALIASTVALK;Initial Catalog=TestEF;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        using (TestEFContext c = new TestEFContext(cs)) {
            User u1 = new User {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UserName = "u1"
            };
            User u2 = new User {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UserName = "u2"
            };
            c.us.Add(u1);
            c.us.Add(u2);
            Task t = new Task {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Creator = u1,
                Owner = u1
            };                
            c.ts.Add(t);
            t = new Task {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Creator = u2,
                Owner = u1
            };
            c.ts.Add(t);
            c.SaveChanges();                
        }

        using (TestEFContext c = new TestEFContext(cs)) {
            var user = c.us
             .Include("TasksCreated")
             .Include("TasksOwned")
             .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals("u1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            foreach (Task t in user.TasksCreated) {
                Console.WriteLine(t.Id);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----");
            foreach (Task t in user.TasksOwned) {
                Console.WriteLine(t.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

displays as expected:

```
a415c8c6-6b0a-4e1b-a42f-cd4230cf4d4a
-----
a415c8c6-6b0a-4e1b-a42f-cd4230cf4d4a
a2e9c527-d8cb-4db7-8879-7febb1c30a07
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

EDITION ========== ==========

the following code runs also:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace testef {
    //Model
    public class Task {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        //other properties that are not relevant here
        public String ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public Guid CreatorId { get; set; }
        public User Creator { get; set; }
        public Guid? OwnerId { get; set; }
        public User Owner { get; set; }
    }

    //Model
    public class User {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        //other properties that are not relevant here
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public IList<Task> TasksCreated { get; set; }
        public IList<Task> TasksOwned { get; set; }
    }

    //Configuration for Task
    public class TaskConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Task> {
        public TaskConfiguration() {
            HasRequired(task => task.Creator)
                .WithMany(creator => creator.TasksCreated)
                .HasForeignKey(task => task.CreatorId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            HasOptional(task => task.Owner)
                .WithMany(owner => owner.TasksOwned)
                .HasForeignKey(task => task.OwnerId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
    public class TestEFContext : DbContext {
        public IDbSet<User> us { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Task> ts { get; set; }

        public TestEFContext(String cs)
            : base(cs) {
            Database.SetInitializer<TestEFContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestEFContext>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TaskConfiguration());            
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(String[] args) {
            String cs = @"Data Source=ALIASTVALK;Initial Catalog=TestEF;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            using (TestEFContext c = new TestEFContext(cs)) {
                User u1 = new User {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    UserName = "u1"
                };
                User u2 = new User {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    UserName = "u2"
                };
                c.us.Add(u1);
                c.us.Add(u2);
                Task t = new Task {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    ShortDescription = "t1",
                    Creator = u1,
                    Owner = u1
                };
                c.ts.Add(t);
                t = new Task {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    ShortDescription = "t2",
                    Creator = u2,
                    Owner = u1
                };
                c.ts.Add(t);
                c.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (TestEFContext c = new TestEFContext(cs)) {
                var user = c.us
                 .Include("TasksCreated")
                 .Include("TasksOwned")
                 .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals("u1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                foreach (Task t in user.TasksCreated) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} is owned by {2}, was created by {3} ", t.ShortDescription, t.Id, t.OwnerId, t.CreatorId);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("-----");

                foreach (Task t in user.TasksOwned) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} is owned by {2}, was created by {3} ", t.ShortDescription, t.Id, t.OwnerId, t.CreatorId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not very clear in what exactly is not working. If you modify your sample so that the Console.WriteLine statement is writing t.OwnerId and add another that writes t.CreatorId, you will see that one of those two values is null even though the Task actually has both populated in the db.

Comment: don't be sorry. I edited my answer but still can't reproduce the behavior :(. BTW I also check by SQL Server Profiler that no lazy loading occurs, just in case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out your sample when I get home tonight. I'll compare against my main code to see what differences there are.

Comment: At this point, the only difference I see is that I'm using Sql Server CE 4. I don't have a full blown Sql Server instance at my disposal to verify. Not even sure if that has anything to do with it.